# Is the IoC container allowed to use the Messenger/Mediator class?

Tags: mvvm, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, mediator, messenger

I'm new with IoC, and i'm wondering if best practices allow the container to use the mediator class, for example MVVM Lite's Messenger. Can the container regiser for and send messages?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your container should not (and doesn't need to), talk to any part of your application. The only point that you should reference your container is at your [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) which is normally in your applications bootstrapper.